# .ssh directory does not exist debian

Tags: ssh, putty

I am trying to set up public-private key authentication by this article
http://www.ualberta.ca/CNS/RESEARCH/LinuxClusters/pka-putty.html

Im on the step of adding public key into `authorized_keys` file, which should be located in `.ssh` directory. But that .ssh directory does not exist. `ls -a` outputs this

```
.    boot         etc         lib         mnt   root     srv  usr
..   dead.letter  home        lost+found  opt   sbin     sys  var
bin  dev          initrd.img  media       proc  selinux  tmp  vmlinuz
```

this does not show any results

```
find / -name 'authorized_keys'
```

So, should I create it, or I should install something and it will appear.

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, you should create the .ssh directory and authorized_keys file if they don't exist.

Create it in the home folder of the user you want to log in as.

Try some thing like this:

```
cd
mkdir .ssh
touch .ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 700 .ssh
chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Then add your key to the `authorized_keys` file.

Alternatively, you can use the command [`ssh-copy-id`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-copy-id) from the source machine to automate the process for you:

```
 ssh-copy-id user@host
```

This will create the `~/.ssh` directory and copy your public key into the file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.